# Highcharts gray.js Theme cannot apply in my Highcharts spline?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, themes, spline

Befor my Highcharts starts in javascript;

```
var chart;
$(document).ready(function () {
```

I have on top;

```
<script src="/Scripts/themes/gray.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And last part of redraw section I have;

```
    Highcharts.setOptions(highchartsOptions);
    chart.redraw;
});
```

I found my gray.js in here: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/themes
which is redirected to me: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/js/themes

but my charts cannot apply gray.js themes. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add themes dynamically, you should destroy chart and create new one.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/themes/gray.js"></script> I just use this line before creating a chart and it worked. Your statement partially right. But I can add button or drop down on page and user can choose which themes to use and create chart very quickly. Its working now. Thank you.